# YUI pagination find current page

Tags: yui

I am using YUI Pagination to show data. How can I populate the default 5th page of my table after updating record of 5th page. And I also need to populate the `RowsPerPageDropdown` value, used to decide how many records to show per page.

Is there a `onChange` event for YUI Pagination? Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're referring to YUI Paginator, yes, there are several [events](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Paginator.html#events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using: YAHOO.widget.Paginator

> pageChange Event fired when attribute changes have
>   resulted in the calculated current page changing.

from: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Paginator.html#events

Used something like this:

```
var paginator = new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({ 
  ... options ...
});
paginator.subscribe('pageChange',function(){
  ... handle page change event ...
})
```

Comment: Relevant examples from developer docs: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/paginator/pag_manual_render.html